# C++ A generic method for writing a vector of Pixels to BMP

Tags: c++, graphics, bitmap

Is it possible to write a class that will take vector of Pixels:

```
struct Pixel
{
    unsigned char Blue;
    unsigned char Green;
    unsigned char Red;
    unsigned char Alpha;
};
```

And generate a BMP from the vector.  I am attempting to start from a basic example, so I am trying with just 4 Pixels, so that is why some of the header values are hard coded.

Here is my header:

```
uint16_t const BITMAP_FILE_TYPE = 0x4d42; //BM, little-endian 
static uint32_t const BITS_PER_BYTE = 8;
static uint32_t const BITS_PER_PIXEL = 24; 

#pragma pack(1) 
struct BITMAPFILEHEADER {
       //uint16_t   bfType;
       uint32_t   bfSize;
       uint16_t   bfReserved1;
       uint16_t   bfReserved2;
       uint32_t   bfOffBits;
}; BITMAPFILEHEADER;

struct BITMAPINFOHEADER {
       uint32_t      biSize;
       int32_t       biWidth;
       int32_t       biHeight;
       uint16_t      biPlanes;
       uint16_t      biBitCount;
       uint32_t      biCompression;
       uint32_t      biSizeImage;
       int32_t       biXPelsPerMeter;
       int32_t       biYPelsPerMeter;
       uint32_t      biClrUsed;
       uint32_t      biClrImportant;
}; BITMAPINFOHEADER;
#pragma pack()

inline uint64_t CalcBitmapFileSize(uint32_t widthBytes, uint32_t height) {
       uint64_t fileSize = widthBytes * height;

       uint32_t padSize = (widthBytes) % sizeof(uint32_t);
       if (padSize > 0) {
              padSize = sizeof(uint32_t) - padSize;
              padSize *= height;
       }
       fileSize += padSize;
       fileSize += sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);


       return fileSize;
}

class BitMapFileWriter
{
public:
    BitMapFileWriter();
    void WriteBMPFile(vector<Pixel> pixelVec, string fileName, uint32_t WIDTH, uint32_t HEIGHT);
};
```

And here is my impl:

```
void BitMapFileWriter::WriteBMPFile(vector<Pixel> pixelVec, string fileName, uint32_t WIDTH, uint32_t HEIGHT)
{
       FILE             *filePtr;          // file pointer
       BITMAPFILEHEADER bitmapFileHeader;  // bitmap file header
       BITMAPINFOHEADER bitmapInfoHeader;  // bitmap info header
       memset(&bitmapFileHeader, 0, sizeof(bitmapFileHeader));
       memset(&bitmapInfoHeader, 0, sizeof(bitmapInfoHeader));

                                                                     // open file for writing binary mode
       filePtr = fopen("C:\\BMP\\4PixelOutPut.bmp", "wb");

       // define the bitmap file header
       //bitmapFileHeader.bfType = BITMAP_FILE_TYPE;
       unsigned short bfType=0x4d42;  
       bitmapFileHeader.bfSize = static_cast<uint32_t>(CalcBitmapFileSize(WIDTH * (BITS_PER_PIXEL / BITS_PER_BYTE), HEIGHT));
       bitmapFileHeader.bfReserved1 = 0;
       bitmapFileHeader.bfReserved2 = 0;
       bitmapFileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(bitmapFileHeader) + sizeof(bitmapInfoHeader);

       // define the bitmap information header
       bitmapInfoHeader.biSize = sizeof(bitmapInfoHeader);
       bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth = WIDTH;                      // bitmap width
       bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight = HEIGHT;                    // bitmap height
       bitmapInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;
       bitmapInfoHeader.biBitCount = BITS_PER_PIXEL;                        
       bitmapInfoHeader.biCompression = 0;               // no compression
       bitmapInfoHeader.biSizeImage = (WIDTH * HEIGHT) * 4;          // width * height
       bitmapInfoHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 5000;
       bitmapInfoHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 5000;
       bitmapInfoHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
       bitmapInfoHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

       fwrite(&bfType,1,sizeof(bfType),filePtr);
                                                                                                   // write the bitmap file header
       fwrite(&bitmapFileHeader, 1, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), filePtr);

       // write the bitmap info header
       fwrite(&bitmapInfoHeader, 1, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), filePtr);

       for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
       {
           Pixel pixel = pixelVec[i];
           fwrite(&pixel.Blue, 1, 1, filePtr);
           fwrite(&pixel.Green, 1, 1, filePtr);
           fwrite(&pixel.Red, 1, 1, filePtr);
       }


       // close our file
       fclose(filePtr);
}
```

And calling it:
    BitMapFileWriter bmfw;
    bmfw.WriteBMPFile(pixelVec,"c:\BMP\4PixelBMP.txt", 2, 2);

Comment: Yes, it is *possible* to write a class that represents a bitmap (or matrix) of pixels and outputs to a BMP format.

Answer (score 1):

I found this class lying around which you might be able to use as reference. It's a "surface" class with members for width, height and a `std::vector` of (32-bit) pixel colors.

Its `Save` member function saves the surface to a .bmp file.  It could easily be transformed into into a stand-alone function taking a width, height and vector.

The `Writer` class wraps an `ofstream` object and supplies the file output interface used in `Save`.

The `BIH` struct should look familiar, and the rest of `Surface`'s member functions provide a very minimal drawing API.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Color {
    union {
        struct { unsigned char b,g,r,a; };
        unsigned char bytes[4];
        unsigned int ref;
    };
    Color(unsigned int ref=0) : ref(ref) {}
};

class Surface {
    int width, height;
    std::vector<Color> pixels;
public:
    void Fill(Color color) { std::fill(pixels.begin(), pixels.end(), color); }
    void HLine(int left, int y, int len, Color color) {
        if(y < 0 || y >= height || left >= width) { return; }
        if(left < 0) { len += left; left = 0; }
        if(left + len > width) { len = width - left; }
        int offset = y * width + left;
        std::fill(pixels.begin() + offset, pixels.begin() + offset + len, color); 
    }
    void RectFill(int x, int y, int w, int h, Color color) {
        for(int i=0; i<h; ++i) { HLine(x, y + i, w, color); }
    }
    Surface(int width, int height) : 
        width(width), 
        height(height),
        pixels(width*height, Color())
    {}
    template <typename I>       Color& operator () (const I& x, const I& y)       { return pixels[y*width+x]; }
    template <typename I> const Color& operator () (const I& x, const I& y) const { return pixels[y*width+x]; }

    class Writer {
        std::ofstream ofs;
    public:
        Writer(const char* filename) : ofs(filename, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary) {}
        void operator () (const void* pbuf, int size) { ofs.write(static_cast<const char*>(pbuf), size); }
        template <typename T> void operator () (const T& obj) { operator () (&obj, sizeof(obj)); }
    };

    struct BIH {
        unsigned int   sz;
        int            width, height;
        unsigned short planes;
        short          bits;
        unsigned int   compress, szimage;
        int            xppm, yppm;
        unsigned int   clrused, clrimp;
    };

    void Save(const char* filename) const {
        Writer w(filename);;
        w("BM", 2);
        BIH bih = {sizeof(bih)};
        bih.width = width;
        bih.height = -height;
        bih.planes = 1;
        bih.bits = 32;
        const unsigned int headersize = sizeof(bih) + 14;
        const int szbuf = int(sizeof(Color) * pixels.size());
        const unsigned int filesize = static_cast<unsigned int>(headersize + szbuf);
        w(filesize);
        const unsigned short z = 0;
        w(z);
        w(z);
        w(headersize);
        w(bih);
        w(pixels.data(), szbuf);
    }
};

int main() {
    Surface surf(600, 600);
    Color color;
    for(int j=0; j<12; ++j) {
        color.g = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<12; ++i) {
            color.b = 255 - (color.g + color.r) / 2;
            surf.RectFill(i*50, j*50, 50, 50, color);
            color.g += 21;
        }
        color.r += 21;
    }
    surf.Save("MyBmpFile.bmp");
}
```